# Import / Export Shopping Cart Price Rules in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have Magento 1.9.1, and I am wondering if there is **anyway** to export **Shopping Cart Price Rules** which is located at Promotions tab and import it into another instance of Magento?

If it is not possible via CSV file, Can I do it from DB level?